# Module not executing with r10k/puppet on masterless system

Tags: debian, puppet, hiera, r10k

I was following [this guide](https://github.com/puppetlabs/r10k/blob/master/doc/dynamic-environments/quickstart.mkd) to set up a masterless puppet machine that could use puppet to manage itself (in a way that would let me add nodes and use this as the master later, but that's irrelevant now).  And I have a basic module set up that should check to make sure nginx is installed and a site config file is there.  But when I run the environment using `sudo r10k deploy environment -p -v`, it seems to update everything, yet the module doesn't seem to be executing properly.

My module can be found [here](https://github.com/cclloyd/ufprovisioning), and my control repo can be found [here](https://github.com/cclloyd/cclloyd-provisioning).

Is my module structured wrong?  Am I missing something here?  Is it because when I check the status of the puppet service using `sudo service puppet status` it spits out a few errors with my `heira.yaml` file?

```
● puppet.service - Puppet agent
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/puppet.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-02-22 23:07:06 UTC; 3min 0s ago
 Main PID: 19319 (puppet)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/puppet.service
           └─19319 /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/ruby /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/puppet agent --no-daemonize

Feb 22 23:07:06 puppeteer systemd[1]: Started Puppet agent.
Feb 22 23:07:07 puppeteer puppet-agent[19319]: Starting Puppet client version 5.4.0
Feb 22 23:07:09 puppeteer puppet-agent[19327]: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, Lookup of key 'classes' failed:  The Lookup Configuration at '/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/hiera.yaml' has wrong type, entry 'hierarchy' index 0 expects a Struct value, got String
Feb 22 23:07:09 puppeteer puppet-agent[19327]:   The Lookup Configuration at '/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/hiera.yaml' has wrong type, entry 'hierarchy' index 1 expects a Struct value, got String
Feb 22 23:07:09 puppeteer puppet-agent[19327]:   The Lookup Configuration at '/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/hiera.yaml' has wrong type, entry 'hierarchy' index 2 expects a Struct value, got String
Feb 22 23:07:09 puppeteer puppet-agent[19327]:   The Lookup Configuration at '/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/hiera.yaml' has wrong type, unrecognized key 'backends'
Feb 22 23:07:09 puppeteer puppet-agent[19327]:   The Lookup Configuration at '/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/hiera.yaml' has wrong type, unrecognized key 'yaml' (file: /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/site.pp, line: 1, column: 1) on node puppeteer.c.personal-server-193919.internal
Feb 22 23:07:09 puppeteer puppet-agent[19327]: Applied catalog in 0.03 seconds
```

Contents of `heira.yaml`:

```
---
# Hiera 5 Global configuration file

version: 5

# defaults:
#   data_hash: yaml_data
# hierarchy:
#  - name: Common
#    data_hash: yaml_data
#hierarchy: [] (tried with and without this commented out)
:backends:
  - yaml
:hierarchy:
  - "%{clientcert}"
  - "%{environment}"
  - global
:yaml:
  :datadir: '/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/environmets/%{environment}/hieradata'
```

Comment: Maybe try putting double-quote around the "global" value in the hierarchy

Comment: It looks like you have a Hiera 3 style hierarchy, but you've defined version 5 at the top of your hiera.yaml file. (The bits that are commented out are Hiera 5 style..) [Hiera: Convert a version 3 hiera.yaml to version 5](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.0/hiera_migrate_v3_yaml.html)